# JSOUP parse Google images

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup, google-image-search

I want to parse Google Images' links to thumbnails and full pictures with JSOUP in Android. The android part actually isn't important as all I need is selector-syntax. 
I searched for tutorials or similar questions but couldn't find any valuable information.

To get images the link is *https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=search-string*.

Below is screenshot of Chrome's Webkit and you can see the link to thumbnail. If I could just get that it would be a good start to try getting links to full images myself.

[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4rEu.jpg)
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why don't you use [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)?

Comment: Can it be used in Android? 
*/EDIT: I've just looked at the posibilities and I think JSOUP is easier, all I would need is selector like "img.rg_hi uh_hi"..

Comment: Google would ban it sooner or later because you're violating their ToS.

Comment: Are there any other "easy parsable" image search engines? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be selecting with `"#rg div.rg_di img"`

So for example something like

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=search-string")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36")
            .get()

doc.select("#rg div.rg_di img")
```

Comment: Its only showing first 20 images how can we get the other images ?